# Why do I get the error message DSolve::dvnoarg: The function succinate appears with no arguments?

Tags: differential-equations

This is my code for a metabolic pathway, I keep getting the error DSolve::dvnoarg: The function succinate appears with no arguments.

```
k1 = 1;
k2 = 1;
k3 = 1;
k4 = 1;
k5 = 1;
sucCD = 0.1;
ATP = 0.5;
scpADIVsbm = 0.1;
AdoCbl = 0.1;
scpBDIVygfG = 0.1;
adhE1 = 0.1;
adhE2 = 0.1;
NADH = 0.5;
DSolve[{succinate'[t] == -k1*succinate[t]*sucCD*ATP,
  succinylCoA'[t] == 
   k1*succinate[t]*sucCD*ATP + k2*succinylCoA[t]*scpADIVsbm*AdoCbl,
  LmmCoA'[t] == 
   k2*succinylCoA[t]*scpADIVsbm*AdoCbl - k3*LmmCoA[t]*scpBDIVygfG,
  propionylCoA'[t] == 
   k3*LmmCoA[t]*scpBDIVygfG - k4*propionylCoA[t]*adhE1*NADH,
  propionaldehyde'[t] == 
   k4*propionylCoA[t]*adhE1*NADH - k5*propionaldehyde[t]*adhE2*NADH,
  propanol'[t] == k5*propionaldehyde[t]*adhE2*NADH, 
  succinate[t] == 20 }, {succinate[t], propanol[t], succinylCoA[t], 
  LmmCoA[t], propionylCoA[t], propionaldehyde[t]}, t]
```

Comment: Can you provide all of the function definitions? Can't do much without them.

Comment: they are not functions, they are just variables like x or y. it is for this pathway                                                                                         SUCCINATE PATHWAY
1) succinate + succCD + ATP → succinyl-CoA + ADP + Pi
2) succinyl-CoA + scpA/sbm + AdoCbl → L-mm-CoA
3) L-mm-CoA + scpB/ygfG → propionyl-CoA + CO2
4) propionyl-CoA + adhE1 + NADH → propionaldehyde + NAD+
5) propionaldehyde + adhE2 + NADH → 1-propanol + NAD+

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Im just trying to set up a set of differential equations to solve for propanol at t. Sorry if this is confusing

Comment: Could it be `succinate[t] == 20`?  Maybe you meant it to be an initial condition, like `succinate[0] == 20`?

Comment: Nice catch, changed it it gave me the same error message but when i changed all the variable names to singular letters and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I  consider that the last equation succinate[t] == 20  might be redundant. Eliminating this returns an answer

```
k1 = 1;
k2 = 1;
k3 = 1;
k4 = 1;
k5 = 1;
sucCD = 0.1;
ATP = 0.5;
scpADIVsbm = 0.1;
AdoCbl = 0.1;
scpBDIVygfG = 0.1;
adhE1 = 0.1;
adhE2 = 0.1;
NADH = 0.5;
DSolve[{succinate'[t] == -k1*succinate[t]*sucCD*ATP, 
  succinylCoA'[t] == 
   k1*succinate[t]*sucCD*ATP + k2*succinylCoA[t]*scpADIVsbm*AdoCbl, 
  LmmCoA'[t] == 
   k2*succinylCoA[t]*scpADIVsbm*AdoCbl - k3*LmmCoA[t]*scpBDIVygfG, 
  propionylCoA'[t] == 
   k3*LmmCoA[t]*scpBDIVygfG - k4*propionylCoA[t]*adhE1*NADH, 
  propionaldehyde'[t] == 
   k4*propionylCoA[t]*adhE1*NADH - k5*propionaldehyde[t]*adhE2*NADH, 
  propanol'[t] == k5*propionaldehyde[t]*adhE2*NADH}, {succinate[t], 
  propanol[t], succinylCoA[t], LmmCoA[t], propionylCoA[t], 
  propionaldehyde[t]}, t]
```

Comment: So i tried that when you responded and it gave me the same error message. I then changed the names of all my variables to singular letters: S, L... and i got back an answer. Thank you very much for the help. Still not quite sure what went wrong.